# Как получить описание пользователя на aiogram который написал /start

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне надо описание профиля пользователя получить который напишет команду. Как это можно сделать на aiogram?

Comment: и в чем сложность? все данные есть в `message`, например `message.chat.username` выдаст ник пользователя, который запустил команду

Answer (score 3):

Для этого есть специальное свойство `message.from_user`.

Описание свойств этого словаря (`message.from_user`):

1. `id`: число
   Идентификатор (ID) пользователя, который использует бота.
2. `is_bot`: булевое значение (`True`/`False`)
   `True`, если это бот;
   `False`, если это не бот.

   Хотя я не уверен, что с ботом когда-то будет разговаривать другой бот.
3. `first_name`: строка
   Имя (first name) пользователя или бота.
4. `last_name`: строка. *Может быть пустой.*
   Фамилия (last name) пользователя или бота.
5. `username`: строка. *Может быть пустой.*
   Имя пользователя или бота в формате `@john`.
6. `is_premium`: булевое значение (`True`/`False`)
   `True`, если пользователь является пользователем Telegram Premium;
   `False`, если пользователь не является.
7. `full_name`: строка
   Имя (first name), и фамилия (last name), собранные воедино.

Все свойства можно использовать через `message.from_user`.

Пример приветствия пользователя ботом, который использует имя и фамилию (*приведён только декоратор с методом*):

```py
# Если ещё не импортирован types, нужно добавить импорт
# from aiogram import types

# Если Dispatcher у вас в другой переменной,
# замените dp на имя вашей переменной с объектом Dispatcher.
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"]): # отвечает на команду start.
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name
    last_name = message.from_user.last_name or "" # предотвращение того, что в ответе будет строка "None"

    await message.reply(f"Привет, {first_name} {last_name}! Это тестовый бот для изучения свойств message.from_user в Aiogram.")
```

*Частично взято из [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/user.html).*

Comment: В [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/user.html).

Comment: Да, я как раз оттуда и взял)